# Multiplication with custom notation

Tags: latex, products, traditional-form

I would like to compute the product

$$(Es+r_{13})(F_{13}s)(F_{3}s+r_{3})(F_{2}s+r_{2})(F_{12}s+r_{12})(F_{1}s+r_{1})(F_{23}s+r_{23})$$

where $E$, $F_i$, and $r_i$ represent arbitrary numbers whose notation makes sense in the general problem I am working on.

When I simply copy and paste the LaTex expression into Mathematica, I get some weird stuff which clearly is not the product.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "(e*s+r_{13})(F_{13}s)(F_{3}s+r_{3})(F_{2}s+r_{2})(F_{12}s+r_{12})(F_{1}s+r_{1})(F_{23}s+r_{23})";
ToExpression[str, TeXForm]

(*    s Subscript[F, 13] (s Subscript[F, 1] + Subscript[r, 1])
      (s Subscript[F, 2] + Subscript[r, 2]) (s Subscript[F, 3] + Subscript[r, 3])
      (s Subscript[F, 12] + Subscript[r, 12]) (e s + Subscript[r, 13])
      (s Subscript[F, 23] + Subscript[r, 23])                     *)
```

Comment: Can I further ask how to ask mathematica to only show the coefficients of s^3 terms in the product?

Comment: Yes, with `Coefficient[%, s^3]`.

Comment: Please note that I've modified the first term from `Es` to `e*s` because `Es` is a single symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space from the pasted-in LaTeX expression so your $Es$, which was interpreted as $E s$, goes back to being  $Es$.

Expression as pasted in:

[image: latex_1]

which evaluates to:

[image: mma_1]

Edit the expression to:

[image: latex_2]

so it now evaluates to:

[image: mma_2]

which is what I presume you want.